# word association - findAssocs and numeric (0)

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm just getting to grips with the `tm` package in R.

Probably a simple question, but trying to use the `findAssocs` function to get an idea for word associations in my customer enquiries insight document and I can't seem to get `findAssocs` to work correctly.

When I use the following:

```
findAssocs(dtm, words, corlimit = 0.30)
 $population
  numeric(0)

 $migration
 numeric(0)
```

What does this mean? `Words` is a character vector of 667 words - surely there must be some correlative relationships?

Comment: It looks like `words` only contains the words `population` and `migration`. Or maybe your `dtm` only contains those two words..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
library(tm)
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(
          c("hello world", "hello another World ", "and hello yet another world")))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)
inspect(tdm)
#          Docs
# Terms     1 2 3
#   and     0 0 1
#   another 0 1 1
#   hello   1 1 1
#   world   1 1 1
#   yet     0 0 1
```

Now consider

```
findAssocs(x=tdm, terms=c("hello", "yet"), corlimit=.4)
# $hello
# numeric(0)
# 
# $yet
#     and another 
#     1.0     0.5
```

From what I understand, `findAssocs` looks at the correlations of `hello` with everything but `hello` and `yet`, as well as `yet` with everything except `hello` and `yet`. `yet` and `and` have a correlation coefficient of `1.0`, which is above the lower limit of `0.4`. `yet` is also in 50% of all documents containing `another` - that's also above our 0.4 limit.

Here's another example showcasing this:

```
findAssocs(x=tdm, terms=c("yet", "another"), corlimit=0)
# $yet
# and 
#   1 
# 
# $another
# and 
# 0.5
```

Note that `hello` (and `world`) don't yield any results because they are in every document. This means the term frequency has zero variance and `cor` under the hood yields `NA` (like `cor(rep(1,3), 1:3)`, which gives `NA` plus a zero-standard-deviation-warning).